# Is there any function in PHP that prints numerical 5 as five?

Tags: php

I want to show numerical 5 as "five". I couldn't explain more than this. Any help please.

Comment: is this expectation is only for 0 to 9 digits?

Comment: You can do a ``switch`` for this

Comment: Or use an array

Comment: or even use basic if else

Comment: So, numbers to words? It's easy. Start trying.

Comment: No, not just limited to 0 - 9. It cn be in thousands also.